# Циклический импорт в Джанго. Как избежать?

Tags: django, импорт, model

Пытаюсь в Джанго связать модели через связь Один ко многим. Три модели в разных приложениях. Возникает ошибка циклического импорта. Как этого избежать, чтобы не переносить модели?
Модель --> Модель --> Модель

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Подсказали. Можно импорт не делать. Прописать строку в виде имени приложения и модели в поле связи:

```
models.ForeignKey('orders.Order',
```

Comment: Если вдруг столкнётесь с тем, что действительно надо будет делать такой импорт - рекомендую почитать про LazyImport.
https://snarky.ca/lazy-importing-in-python-3-7/